# Get current logged in User and set as default user on Model | Django + Python3

Tags: python, django

I'm learning about Django, and challenged myself to create an small Ticket System as study case.

Got some things done, but now i'm with a little problem.

How to when i save an "Ticket", Django get current logged in user and set as default on "usuario" field from my Ticket model?

This is my `models.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Projeto(models.Model):
    """
        Classe que gere os Projetos
        Permite que se cadastre N usuários por Projeto
        Retorna:
            NOME_DO_PROJETO | SITE_DO_PROJETO
    """
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    informacoes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    usuarios = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projetos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome + " | " + self.site

class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
        Classe que gere os Tickets no sistema.
        Retorna:
            DATA HORA | TITULO DO CHAMADO
    """
    TIPOS_TICKET = (
        ('BUG', 'Bug'),
        ('URGENTE', 'Urgente'),
        ('FINANCEIRO', 'Financeiro'),
        ('MELHORIA', 'Melhoria')
    )
    STATUS_TICKET = (
        ('ABERTO', 'Aberto'),
        ('AGUARDANDO_CLIENTE', 'Aguardando Cliente'),
        ('EM_ANALISE', 'Em Análise'),
        ('FINALIZADO', 'Finalizado'),
        ('CANCELADO', 'Cancelado'),
    )
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    conteudo = models.TextField()
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TIPOS_TICKET, default='BUG')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_TICKET, default='ABERTO')
    projeto = models.ForeignKey(
        Projeto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'usuarios':1}
    )
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    data_abertura = models.DateTimeField('Data Abertura', auto_now_add=True)
    data_fechamento = models.DateTimeField('Data Fechamento', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(datetime.strftime(self.data_abertura, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M") + " | " + self.titulo)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usuario = User
        super(Ticket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TicketMsg(models.Model):
    """
        Mensagens dos tickets
        Retorna:
            texto da mensagem
    """
    texto = models.TextField()
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_resposta = models.DateTimeField('Data Resposta')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.texto)
```

And my `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Ticket, TicketMsg, Projeto

# Register your models here.
class ProjetoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Projeto
    filter_horizontal = ('usuarios',)

class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Ticket
    exclude = ('status', 'data_fechamento', 'data_abertura', 'usuario')
    list_display = ('titulo', 'tipo', 'status', 'projeto', 'data_abertura')
    list_filter = ('projeto', 'tipo', 'status')

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['data_abertura']

admin.site.register(Projeto, ProjetoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ticket, TicketAdmin)
admin.site.register(TicketMsg)
```

This is my ticket list from Django Admin.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

The idea, is to use default Django user system to identify who is trying to open an ticket.

I made with success the system filter what projects each user can open tickets to, but now i can't set as default value who is the current user who are typing the new Ticket.

This is my form actually.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

All help is welcome!
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently loggedin user is attached on the *request* object as part of Djangos Request-Response-Lifecycle. You can not access the *request* in methods of the model (like you wanted to do in the *save()* method).

However, you can override the *save_model()* method of the admin form, where the *request* is available:

```
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Ticket
    exclude = ('status', 'data_fechamento', 'data_abertura', 'usuario')
    list_display = ('titulo', 'tipo', 'status', 'projeto', 'data_abertura')
    list_filter = ('projeto', 'tipo', 'status')

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['data_abertura']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.usuario = request.user
        super(TicketAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

There is no need to override the save() method on your model then.

More info about the ModelAdmin on the official Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: Saddly it does not works.

here is the answer:
`ValueError at /admin/tickets/ticket/add/
Cannot assign "<class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>": "Ticket.usuario" must be a "User" instance.`

Comment: I guess you didn't delete the save() method on the Ticket model as I stated in the answer. The error is telling you, that you cannot assign User to usuario; which makes sense, usuario is a User instance. Sadly you didn't copy the lines the part of the stack trace that contains the faulty lines of code. In the future you can check those which easily hints you to the problem.